# Creating an Android Application with a services layer

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, service

I would like to know what developers that use Android on a daily basis, use as their services layer (between app and production database)

In the Microsoft space, there is WCF.

What can the Android Developers recommend?

Comment: You could still use WCF, I have in the past and it works fine. I think it more so depends on the particular needs of a project.

Comment: Could you please specify what did you use to link the 2 platforms? Did you use mono? or java libraries that can interop with wcf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key point of having a service over http is to abstract away how the service is built. So you should not be worried about it.

Having said that, in smartphones, it is advisable to build and consume light weight REST based services over JSON instead of heavy SOAP and XML based services. How you implement the REST service is actually immaterial.